# Form continue confirmation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, confirmation

I have a simple html form which is submitting to it's self. If any of the checkboxes on the form are ticketed I want to ask the user if they want to continue.

I only want to ask them once, NOT once for each checkbox.

This is what I currently have :

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
<tr>
<td><input name="u_a" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input name="a"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="u_b" type="checkbox"></td> <td><input name="b"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="u_c" type="checkbox"></td> <td><input name="c"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2" rowspan="1"><input type="hidden" name="update" value="update"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['update'])) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['u_a']) || isset($_REQUEST['u_b']) || isset($_REQUEST['u_c'])) {
// CONFIRM CONTINUE OK=CONTINUE CANCEL=EXIT
    }
}
?>
```

How do I do the confirmation alert, and make the processing stop if they click cancel.
If they click cancel I'd like there form values to remain so they can adjust them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm). It allows you to base your logic on the response from the user.

```
if (window.confirm("Are you sure you wish to update?")) { 
  // yes, do something
}
```

Comment: You need to use jquery to stop the default behaviour. `preventDefault()` should do it.